# Find duplicate in a list from a reference list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I'd like know if at least one element of listRef is present more than once in listA ? The other values can be present more than once.

```
List<string> listA = new List<string> { "A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
List<string> listRef = new List<string> { "B", "D" };
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
bool hasRef = listref.Any(r => listA.Count(a => a == r) > 1);
```

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek not sure about that as there is a condition inside. it depends on how complier going to assemble it.

Comment: @G.Y Compiler has nothing to do here.

Comment: if it going to compile the inner part to "if >1 then break".. the performance will not take a hit.

Comment: @G.Y: The perf hit here is not due to compilation but due to the fact that `listA` will possibly be iterated over a lot. But the end result depends on the size of the input -- for small lists this will still be faster than anything else, much like for sorting small lists selection sort is faster than quicksort.

Answer (score 5):

I would use `ToLookup` method to generate `Lookup<string, string>` first, and then use it to check your condition:

```
var lookup = listA.ToLookup(x => x);
return listRef.Any(x => lookup.Contains(x) && lookup[x].Count() > 1);
```

You could use `GroupBy` and `ToDictionary` to achieve the same:

```
var groups = listA.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
return listRef.Any(x => groups.ContainsKey(x) && groups[x] > 1);
```

Comment: There is a typo `lookup.Containt(Contains)` should be `lookup.Contains(x)`

Answer (score 2):

something like this

```
    var query = listRef.Where(x=>
        listA.Where(a => a == x)
             .Skip(1)
             .Any());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listRef.ForEach(refEl => {

   var count = listA.Count(aEl => aEl == refEl);
   if(count > 1) {

      //Do something

   }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Finding the best performing option in this case is not simple because that depends on the number of items in the lists and the expected result.

Here's a way to do it that is performant in the face of big lists:

```
var appearances = listA.GroupBy(s => s)
                       .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                       .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
var hasItemAppearingMoreThanOnce = listRef.Any(r => appearances.ContainsKey(r));
```

Comment: Calling `Count()` on every group twice will cause two enumerations on every group. It can be done using only one.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: That's a valid point, but it depends on the type of enumerable returned by `GroupBy`. I am (perhaps wrongly) assuming that each group can get its count in constant time, because if not then the implication is that `list.GroupBy(o => o).SelectMany(g => g)` is quadratic on the length of `list`, which to me sounds unreasonable behavior coming from a library implementation. But good point, I 'll go check.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: As I thought, `Count()` on an item returned by `GroupBy()` is constant time. Play with [this code](http://pastebin.com/dWpkTb6Q) to see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
    List<string> listA = new List<string> { "A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
    List<string> listRef = new List<string> { "A", "D" };
    foreach (var item in listRef)
    {
        if (listA.Where(x => x.Equals(item)).Count() > 1)
        { 
        //item is present more than once
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = listA.GroupBy(x=>x)
                  .Where(g=>g.Count()>1&&listRef.Contains(g.Key))
                  .Select(x=>x.First());
bool a = result.Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be another way to do

```
        List<string> listA = new List<string> { "A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" , "D" };
        List<string> listRef = new List<string> { "B", "D" };

        var duplicates = listA.GroupBy(s => s).SelectMany(grp => grp.Skip(1));
        var newData = duplicates.Select(i => i.ToString()).Intersect(listRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the second list is large and can contain duplicates i would use a `HashSet<string>` and `IntersectWith` to remove possible duplicates and `strings` which are not in the first list from the second:

```
var refSet = new HashSet<string>(listRef);
refSet.IntersectWith(listA);
bool anyMoreThanOne = refSet.Any(rs => listA.ContainsMoreThanOnce(rs, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Here the extension which is not very elegant but works:

```
public static bool ContainsMoreThanOnce(this IEnumerable<string> coll, String value, StringComparison comparer)
{
    if (coll == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("col");
    bool contains = false;
    foreach (string str in coll)
    {
        if (String.Compare(value, str, comparer) == 0)
        {
            if (contains)
                return true;
            else
                contains = true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/WRheCF)</kbd>

However, if the second `listRef` isn't large or doesn't contain duplicates you can just use:

```
bool anyMoreThanOne = listRef
  .Any(rs => listA.ContainsMoreThanOnce(rs, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```